# Slow join query - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, join

I'm trying to perform a simple query in Entity Framework.

I have a list of funky things

```
List<FunkyThing> funkyThings;
```

Which has 1-5 unique `FunkyThing`'s in it.

```
FunkyThing
{
   string FunkyThingUniqueCustomerCode{get;set}
   string UsefullInfoRegardFunkyThings{get;set}
}
```

I'm trying to do a join onto the funky things table in my database.

The table looks something along the lines of:

**FunkyThingsTable**

```
int ID
string UniqueCustomerCode 
string colour
string usefulInfoOfGreatValue
decimal cost
```

Now as it so happens there's approximately 300,000 funky things in this table.

What I was hoping to do is join my list on to my table to get the usefulInfoOfGreatValue element out. As follows:

```
var listOfFunkyThingsUsefulInfoQuery = from funkyThing in funkyThings
                                   join
                                      funkyThingDBEntity in unitOfWork.FunkyThingsRepository.Get()
                                      on funkyThing.FunkyThingUniqueCustomerCode equals funkyThingDBEntity .UniqueCustomerCode

                                  select new
                                  {
                                      uniqueCode= funkyThingDBEntity .UniqueCustomerCode,
                                      usefulInfoOfGreatValue= funkyThingDBEntity .usefulInfoOfGreatValue
                                  };
```

Unfortunately the query takes about 5 seconds to run -even with just one item in the list. What am I doing wrong?

A few quick notes. I'm using the unit of work pattern as described here:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

The customers for long technical reasons don't have the integer ID, only a string customer code - hence this comparison.

Additional Notes:
As per the unit of work article the unitOfWork.FunkyThingsRepository.Get() returns an IEnumerable:

```
 public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get
```

I've just tried re-working so use lambda as follows:

```
var listOfFunkyThingsUsefulInfoQuery = unitOfWork.FunkyThingsRepository.Get().Join (funkyThings, funkyThingDBEntity=>funkyThingDBEntity.UniqueCustomerCode, funkyThings=>funkyThings.FunkyThingUniqueCustomerCode ,(funkyThings,funkyThingDBEntity)=>new {uniqueCode= funkyThingDBEntity .UniqueCustomerCode, usefulInfoOfGreatValue=funkyThingDBEntity .usefulInfoOfGreatValue}) ;
```

However sadly this takes the same amount of time

Comment: I would suspect doing `unitOfWork.FunkyThingsRepository.Get()` on every row would be the cause. What does this do?

Comment: It returns an IEnumerable TEntity as per the article:

Comment: @ChrisNevill Remove the above comment and add it to your question

Comment: Comment removed and appended to article

Comment: @ChrisNevill - I meant *how* does it work> Does it make an expensive call to the database? Does it try to connect to a remote server? That sort of thing.

Comment: At present the whole solutions running on my laptop - which is quick.  The slowness does seem to come from this Get retrieving all the rows before doing the join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query will cause all 300,000 rows be retrieved from the database to memory and perform the join there. Looking at your query, all you're trying to do is extract `UsefulInfoOfGreatValue` associated with the items in `funkyThings` based on `UniqueCustomerCode`.

In the article, the `Get()` method has a filter parameter that defaults to null. You can set this filter to make your query much faster (i.e. only get the rows you need)

Try this

```cs
var funkyThingsCustomerCodes = funkyThings.Select(x => x.FunkyThingUniqueCustomerCode).ToList();

var listOfFunkyThingsUsefulInfoQuery =
      from funkyThing in unitOfWork.FunkyThingsRepository.Get(e => funkyThingsCustomerCodes.Contains(e.UniqueCustomerCode))
      select new {
        UniqueCode = funkyThing.UniqueCustomerCode,
        UsefulInfoOfGreatValue = funkyThing.UsefulInfoOfGreatValue
      };
```

Also if you create an index on `UniqueCustomerCode` column in your table the above query will be even much faster.

Comment: This worked for this particular problem- thanks Alaa.  My only concern is that in other places in the project I am going to need an inner join.  It seems to me at the moment using this unit of work solution I can't see how I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

try to use eager loading, and use include statement. It will be little faster. Please go through below links, it might help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/07/migrating-from-linq-to-sql-to-entity-framework-eager-loading.aspx